# How to change custom post type category link in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Hi I'm building a wordpress application with custom post type. Having trouble with custom post type.

This is my following code for custom post type

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Movies', 'movie' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'movie', 'movie' ),
    'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'movie' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New movie', 'movie' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit movie', 'movie' ),
    'new_item' => _x( 'New movie', 'movie' ),
    'view_item' => _x( 'View movie', 'movie' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Search Movies', 'movie' ),
    'not_found' => _x( 'No Movies found', 'movie' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No Movies found in Trash', 'movie' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent movie:', 'movie' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'Movies', 'movie' ),
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'description' => 'movie Collections',
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'page-category' ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/movie.png',
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
          'slug'=>'collection',
     ),
    'capability_type' => 'page'

);

register_post_type( 'movie', $args );
```

I've rewrite the post type URL to `collections`. but under my collection page, I'm displaying all movies category. This is my code

```
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'category' );
  echo wp_list_categories( $args );
```

Problem is the category link is displaying like this `http://localhost/films/category/action/` But I want to change it like this `http://localhost/films/collection/category/action/`

Answer (score 1):

you achieve this using [post_type_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_type_link) filter available in WordPress

```
function filter_post_type_link($link, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type != 'movie')
        return $link;

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'movie'))
        $link = str_replace('%category%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
```

Check [this answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks) which may help you

It is also worth looking [term_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/term_link) filter